# too many conditions

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have this piece of code I developed but it doesn't look efficient to me, can anyone improve it please.

```
 private void AddToDataBase(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        DataAccess DA = new DataAccess(ConnectionString());

        DetailsRow result = DA.GetDetails(properties.WebUrl);

        if (result != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.URL))
        {
            DA.DeleteDetails(properties.WebUrl);
        }

        if (bool.Parse(properties.ListItem.Properties["Regular Customer"].ToString()) == true)
        {
            DA.InsertDetails(properties.Name, properties.WebUrl, DateTime.Now);
        }
        else
        {
            if (NumberOfInvoices(properties) > 0)
            {
                DA.InsertDetails(properties.Name, properties.WebUrl, DateTime.Now);
            }

            else
            {
                DeleteInvoiceDocument(properties);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello TimeToThine. How do you suppose anyone can answer that **without knowing what your conditions are?** Your question is at risk of being closed as "not a real question" if you don't include this critical information. By the way, your assumption is probably wrong - even *if* the code is different, it can have a big influence on the possible refactorings, so you should show that too.

Comment: basically my conditions are just checking few results returned by a DataTable and it checks if they are null or not + few other validations, I want this code to be reviewed based on structure of it as I got 1 empty "else" statement in there which doesn't look great to me to be honest :)

Comment: This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about [what your code does](//codereview.meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1226) and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  The current title states your concerns about the code; it needs an [edit] to simply *state the task*; see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since I don't have the SharePoint libraries I wasn't able to test my solution, but it should work.

1. Use proper indentation and formatting.
2. `== true` is redundant and can be removed.
3. Instead of the following:

   ```cs
   bool.Parse(properties.ListItem.Properties["Regular Customer"].ToString())
   ```

   just *convert to `bool`* (casting won't work because of SharePoint):

   ```cs
   Convert.ToBoolean(properties.ListItem.Properties["Regular Customer"])
   ```
4. Reduce nesting by using `else if` instead of `else { if (...) }`
5. Use `||` instead of two seperate conditions with the same associated code to avoid redundancy.

---

**Result of refactoring**

```cs
private void AddToDataBase(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    DataAccess dataAccess = new DataAccess(ConnectionString());
    DetailsRow result = dataAccess.GetDetails(properties.WebUrl);
    bool isRegular = Convert.ToBoolean(properties.ListItem.Properties["Regular Customer"])

    if (result != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.URL))
    {
        dataAccess.DeleteDetails(properties.WebUrl);
    }

    if (isRegular || NumberOfInvoices(properties) > 0)
    {
        dataAccess.InsertDetails(properties.Name, properties.WebUrl, DateTime.Now);
    }
    else
    {
        DeleteInvoiceDocument(properties);
    }
}
```

Comment: my code is ignoring rest of code after this line "bool isRegularCustomer = (bool)properties.ListItem.Properties["Regular Customer"];" tried debugging but when it comes to this line it simply refreshes SharePoint page and there's nothing left to process

Comment: the cast to bool seems to be throwing an exception. try using the old version `isRegularCustomer = bool.Parse(...ToString())` instead.

Comment: its something related to sharepoint I guess, I tried it so many times before as you suggested but never worked, so used to prase it

Comment: hm... according to [this comment on a related StackOverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033988/getting-value-from-spfieldboolean#comment4328627_4034070), `Convert.ToBoolean` should also work.

Comment: Is convert.ToBoolean is better then bool.prase

Comment: I prefer it because we can leave out the call to `ToString()`. There are some [subtle differences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031964/what-is-the-difference-between-convert-tobooleanstring-and-boolean-parsestrin), but the main reason for me is that `Convert.ToBoolean` will work with any compatible type, not just with `string`.